# Initializer_list as function parameter and for loop in function

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm new here and this is my first question.

So, I have this function:

```
std::string join(string_initializer_list p_input) const {
    std::string output;
    for (auto const & s : p_input) {
        output.append(s);
    }
    return output;
}
```

The main objective of that function is to join a list of strings returning a new string.

For the parameter I've used a `std::initializer_list<std::string>` aliased as `string_initializer_list`.

The parameter is passed by value because after doing a bit of research, I noticed that I was just passing pointers around and that this was the most idiomatic and correct way to do so.

My question has to do with the for loop: which is more correct in this case and why? Should I use `auto const &` or `auto &&`?

The thing is: I don't want to change any of the strings from the `initializer_list`, and I want to leave that clear. From that perspective `const &` seems more correct but I would to know your opinions about this matter.

After doing some research, testing it in C++ and reading lots of questions here, I don't yet fully understand how `auto &&` works.

Also, in a first draft I also had the parameter being passed as `&&` as a way to prevent it from being an lvalue.

I intend only to use this function for quick stuff like this:

```
join({"Hello, ", "world"});
```

In rare ocasions, one of those `std::string`s will end up being an lvalue:

```
join({"Hello, ", some_string});
```

The main concept here is to make a cheap and easy way of concatenating strings. This is another function I made, similar with the one above but for a different context.

```
std::string & concatenate(std::string & p_output, string_initializer_list p_input) const {
    for (auto const & s : p_input) {
        p_output.append(s);
    }
    return p_output;
}
```

Once more, the perfectionist in me is asking about that for loop.

Comment: A couple of things you might want to consider in your function. One would be that you probably want to first compute the sum of the lengths, and then construct a string of that size before filling it in. As for the loop. It won't matter much whether you use const auto& or auto&& in the grand scheme of things as the underlying object types are of type const string so type deduction for the universal reference should yield const string& same as const auto& would. (A more efficient function might actually be one using variadic templates to do the work instead of a loop.)

Comment: Thanks! Should I use another loop to calculate the final length and then call reserve on the final string? Wouldn't another loop be a bit too much? I mean, I understand your point. I knew about the variadic template thing, the problem with the template solution is that, well, they should be generic and in my case I just want something that works on strings, also many implementations of variadic templates for string concatenation uses ostringstream just to ensure that most of the stuff gets turned into a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iterator type of `std::initializer_list<T>` is `const T*`. So when you dereference it, you get an lvalue of type `const T`. It does not matter whether you use `const auto&` or `auto&&` to iterate since either way you will get an lvalue reference to `const T`. I would prefer `const auto&` here for readability---`auto&&` often suggests you're working with template code in which the thing could be either an lvalue or an rvalue.

Comment: Thanks for the response ;)